# Theme reflection

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Magento 1.9.x
Hello,

I have a diwali theme and all caching is enabled.
I have given theme start-end date.

So, my question is, do the theme diwali reflected at given start-date,
or I have to flush the cache at the given date ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to change the theme in backend at the time of diwali.... you can change Theme by **System > Configuration > General > Design** and **Flush the cache**

[image]

Comment: You mean if I set 12:00 o'clock  as start-date, 
I have to wake up before 12:00 o'clock and flush the magento cache to
reflect my theme.
No doubt, that I can't set time, just the date.
Do you think is it a feasible solution ?

Comment: @BMK usually in magento sites there will be no option to  set `start-date` for theme, best option is to dont wait until diwali....  you can check that in demo/staging site..... change the theme and set the `start date` and `flush the cache` ....  and check tomorow whether the theme will reflect or not ......

Comment: Thanks for responding.
But still I need to flush the cache, is it necessary ?

Comment: @BMK once you set `start date` and flush the cache, for my knowledge, the diwali theme appy at the set date and time, no need to flush cache again..... but i sugggest you to check that in demo site instead of experimenting in live site.....